# Are there any hiking challenges around Quebec City?

Tags: hiking, quebec

I will be visiting Quebec City later this summer and want to spend some time hiking. In NY (where I live) there are various hiking challenges one can complete. For example: hiking the 12 mountains around Lake George or the 6 mountains around Saranac Lake. Completion of these challenges makes an individual eligible to have their name on the official list and often to receive a hiking patch/badge. I am wondering if there any such challenges in Quebec.

Answer (score 2):

Each administrative region might have their own type of challenge. From what I found, the region of Charlevoix (which is magnificent and relatively close to Quebec City) provide some type of certificate to anyone able to climb the 5 mountain tops around the region. Sadly, their website is only in French: https://www.traverseedecharlevoix.qc.ca/defides5sommets

From the inscription form, a translation of what to do would be:
The five summits are:
The Mont Élie, the Mont des Morios, the Acropole des Draveurs, the Mont-du-Lac-des-Cygnes and the Mont du Lac-à-l'Empêche et Du Four.
The dates are: from 10th of June to October 31st, 2017!
The pictures must be sent to defides5sommets@hotmail.com

You have to fill the inscription form, then climb the mountains and take pictures from each summit and send them to the email address.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the hiking options are around the city, but it's easy enough to forget Quebec City itself is built on a hill (It's actually the only fragment of the Appalachian region--As it's known in Canada--that is located West of the Saint Lawrence River), and it is lined with cliffs. There are about 30 stairs that connect the ''Haute-Ville'' and the ''Basse-Ville'', and there's a hiking/running challenge, the *Défi Escaliers* that involve climbing a bunch of them. [I managed to find a map.](https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?mid=1OuaFyNHZvYErgMOYqbhO-mJY5qY)